# how to combine regex in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

could you please tell me 
how to combine regex in jquery ? .I have function to validate mobile number.But I am using three (3) regex I want to combine to one (1).
can we do that

here is my code
https://jsbin.com/japokekiji/edit?html,js,console,output

**valid number**

```
+919313854539

9313854539

09313854539

$(function(){
  var _const ={
     validMobileNumber: ['7777777777', '8888888888', '9999999999']
  }
  $('input').on('keyup',function(){
    console.log(validMobileNumber($(this).val()));
  })
      function validMobileNumber(mobileNumber) {
        var regWithoutZero = /^([7-9])[0-9]{9}$/;
        var regWithZero = /^(0)[7-9][0-9]{9}$/;
        var regWithCountryCode = /^(\+91)[7-9][0-9]{9}$/;
        var isValid = false;
        if (mobileNumber != "" && mobileNumber != null) {
            if (_const.validMobileNumber.indexOf(mobileNumber)!=-1) {
                isValid = false;
            }
            else if (regWithoutZero.test(mobileNumber) || regWithZero.test(mobileNumber) || regWithCountryCode.test(mobileNumber)) {
                isValid = true;
            }
            else {
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
})
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read up on regular expressions, and how for example alternation works?

Comment: i google and tried ..that why i write 3 regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends, for instance if you want to test with an OR operator, this would be something like this :

```
var mergedRegex = /^(([7-9])[0-9]{9}|(0)[7-9][0-9]{9}|(\+91)[7-9][0-9]{9})$/;
```

If you want with an AND operator, try this instead :

```
var mergedRegex = /^(?=([7-9])[0-9]{9})(?=(0)[7-9][0-9]{9})(?=\+91)[7-9][0-9]{9})$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with :

`var mergedRegex = /^(\+91|0)?[7-9][0-9]{9}$/`

I would advise reading up [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), if you want to learn all there is to know about regexes.